# Name and create variables dynamically in for loop (VBA)

Tags: excel, vba, variables, dynamic

Can variables be named and assigned dynamically in VBA any other way?

```vb
Sub variables()
    
    Dim lastCol As Long
    lastCol = Sheet1.Cells.Find(What:="*", SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, LookAt:=xlWhole).Column
    
    Dim i As Long
    For i = 1 To lastCol
        Dim colIndex(Cells(1, i).Value) As Long
        colIndex(Cells(1, i)) = Cells(1, i).Column
    Next i
    
End Sub
```

But when I try to run it I see this error:

> Compile Error:
>
> Constant expression required

Comment: use ReDim instead of Dim. The values used inside those parenthesis must be of Long Type

Comment: What is `col` in `col(Cells(1, i)).Column`? What do you expect the output to be here?

Comment: If you want to keep the values you've already stored in the array, use `ReDim Preserve`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you cannot do this. What you can do is create an array of the appropriate size, with a spot for each of the variables you will need.